How to Implement SIP-based Voice Calling and Messaging in a React Native App?
I'm looking to create a React Native app that supports voice calling and messaging using SIP (Session Initiation Protocol). However, I'm having difficulty finding a suitable library or SDK to achieve this, especially with up-to-date support.
I’ve already explored these libraries:

@aldiand/react-native-pjsip - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aldiand/react-native-pjsip
react-native-pjsip - https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip

Unfortunately, they seem outdated or lacking the functionality I need. Has anyone successfully implemented SIP for voice calling and messaging in React Native? If so, I’d really appreciate any recommendations for libraries, SDKs, or guidance on building this.
Thank you!

Hi, looking for the same thing. Have you found any solution?

No, not yet thinking of using native code and bridging it in React native. If you have found any solution please let me know
